# WSO2 AM 1.10.0 Swagger json export

Tags: wso2, swagger, wso2-api-manager

I added swagger API doc into Restful services and can be invoked as below,

[image: swagger json]

I created new APIs of the services in AM and they are working well,

[image: API]

However, I do not know how to use WSO2 AM to export the swagger file as users ask the APIs definition file.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Try this: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

Answer (score 0):

You can export swagger file in APIM. In publisher go to edit API. Then, in Design tab, click `Edit Source` link.

[image]

Then Swagger editor will open. Then you can Download swagger file by `File > Download...`