# How to configure existing api in wso2 Api Publisher?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 api manager.I want to configure the existing api in api publisher.
I have few question.

1)After choosing "I have existing Api" radio button, two option populates

a)swagger file     b)swagger url.

For first option, from where swagger file will generate? and how to generate?

For second option, which url api publisher expecting?

2)After choosing the swagger url radio button. on next page import option is present which also shows same option as above.Whats use of this option and which one to choose.

I tried with the swagger url in both condition and click on save button then it shows below error message.

{"error" : true, "message" : "Invalid CSRF Token please try refreshing the page."}

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue also please share some link or documentation for configuration of existing api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APIM, when you select "I have existing API", that means you already have a swagger document for the API. If that's not what you want (i.e. you don't have a swagger doc), you can proceed with `Create New API` option.

Edit:
What do you mean by an existing API here? Are you just having a service which needs to be exposed as a manage service? If yes, `Create New API` is the way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to create the swagger api document?If You have any link or documentation , please share so i can follow

Comment: If  you don't have a swagger doc, use `Create New API` option. It will create a swagger doc internally.

Comment: If you want to write it manually, you can use http://editor.swagger.io. The same is included in APIM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028544/wso2-am-1-10-0-swaggle-json-export/39030695#39030695

Comment: Thank you . Now i am able to import the swagger json url in api manager publisher.But i am facing very small problem now. In api store every request path end with *.For e.g I am configuring /getname/ path in publisher for service but in store it becomes /getname/* instead of only /getname/.

Comment: In Api publisher request url configured is https:\\localhost:8080\myApp\getname\ and when I check the same Url in Api Store it becomes https:\\localhost:8080\myApp\getname\*.In short In store url  \getname\ is configured and in store it shows \getname\*.

Comment: I think it's a known issue in swagger ui.